# How to Create a Log Axis and include all tic labels in Zedgraph (C#)

Tags: c#, logging, zedgraph

I have multiple graphs using Zedgraph in a project, and I have met with great success.  The only issue I am running into is formatting a log type axis the way I want it.  I managed to get rid of the scientific notation, but I want to include more than just the powers of 10 in my labels.

A little clarification: I would like to keep the data formatted in a log scale, but display labels more like a regular linear graph.

Has anyone had an success with this?  I have no problem editing the source if need be, just having a hard time finding the best place to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, just in case anyone else is looking for this answer, I have found it.  There may be a way without editing the source code, but it is a real easy fix.  You just open up the source and navigate to the LogScale class.  There is a method called PickScale, and it contains the code that defaults the step to 1.  In a log axis, this step is the exponent, so by lowering it you can get more values than just 10s.